# np.where(condition is None) not equal to np.where(condition == None)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm troubled with the np.where() function. (line 7 in my example)

**Background:** I am programming the game "Connect Four". This `insert_chip()` method accesses the variable `self.board` which is an 8x8 np array of my personal dtype `Chip`. If there is no `chip` in an entry of `self.board`, then the value is `None`.

For some reason, `np.where(col_entries is None)` does not return the indices of the elements that are `None`. And why do I receive a different output, when I write `col_entries == None` in the condition? It's not a if `None` has a reference right?

```
def insert_chip(self, chip, col):
    # slices the entries of the column into a new array
    col_entries = self.board[:, col:col+1]

    # checks for all unoccupied pos in this col (entries are None)
    # gives double array of indexes with the form (array([row_i, ...]), array([col_i, ...]))
    none_indexes = np.where(col_entries is None)

    # the pos where the chip will fall is the one with the highest index
    self.board[len(none_indexes[0]), col] = chip
```

Comment: `is` checks if `col_entries` (so thye matrix itself) is `None`. So this is *always* `False`.

Comment: [This site](https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python) is a good place to check for understanding the difference between `is` and `==` in python.

Comment: Compare `(col_entries is None)` with`(col_entries==None)`.  The test is done first, and then passed to `where`.  If the test array doesn't make sense, then the `where` result won't either.

Comment: None ALWAYS needs to be checked with `is`. Anything else isn't safe.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `self.board`?  `object` or numeric?  Math with a numeric dtype is faster, but it can't hold a `None` object. And object dtype array is more like a list, or if 2d, a list of lists.

Comment: @hpaulj it's an object dtype array.

Comment: @PhilippWulff: what else does this array contains?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make an object dtype array:

```
In [37]: arr = np.zeros((3,3), object)
In [39]: arr[range(3),range(3)]=None
In [40]: arr
Out[40]: 
array([[None, 0, 0],
       [0, None, 0],
       [0, 0, None]], dtype=object)
```

The `is None` test:

```
In [41]: arr is None
Out[41]: False
```

The == test.

```
In [42]: arr == None
Out[42]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
In [43]: np.where(arr == None)
Out[43]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

Propagation of comparison tests in object arrays has been undergoing some changes.  From a recent release_notes: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html#comparison-ufuncs-accept-dtype-object-overriding-the-default-bool

---

Similar operations on a list

```
In [44]: alist = [0,None,0]
In [45]: alist is None
Out[45]: False
In [46]: [i is None for i in alist]
Out[46]: [False, True, False]
In [48]: alist.index(None)
Out[48]: 1
```

Answer (score 7):

> For some reason, `np.where(col_entries is None)` does not return the indices of the elements that are `None`.

The `is` operator checks if the two operands point to the same object. So here it checks if `col_entries` (the matrix) is `None`, it thus does *not* performs "broadcasting" to check if some elements in the matrix refer to `None`.

In Python one can overload certain operators like `<=`, `==`, etc. Numpy makes use of that to implement specific operators, such that one can write `some_matrix == 0` to generate a matrix of booleans. The `is` operator can *not* be overloaded, and so Numpy (nor any other library) has control over this. `is` simply checks if the two operands refer to the same object.

Since here your `col_entries` refers to a numpy array, this will always be `False`, hence `np.where(col_entries is None)` will always return an 1-tuple containing an empty array.

Although there are not that much objects that are equal to `None`, it is still not very safe to count on that. We can vectorize the `is` operator, like:

```
from operator import is_

np.where(np.vectorize(is_)(col_entries, None))
```

Comment: This explanation helps me. So should one use `==` instead?

Comment: I think you should use `is_` instead of `is` in your vectorize argument.